# Error Calling GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-2015

[Attempting to follow the example to access data on builds](https://armandlacore.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/tfs-powershell/). I am doing this in PowerShell on the TFS Server being referenced. TFS 2015 Update 3 is installed. The server was stood up about 6 months ago with TFS 2015 Update 2 as the original version installed.

I have successfully loaded all assemblies mentioned, mostly via Add-Type but a couple using reflection.

Successfully created ProjectsCollection object and verified that it authenticated.

On this call:

```
 $buildServer = $projectCollections.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
```

I get the following error:

> Exception calling "GetService" with "1" argument(s): "TF214015: The build client object model does not support Team Foundation Server 2005 or Team Foundation Server 2008"

Does it think I'm running an old version of TFS and, if so, how is that possible when those versions have never been installed. Googling the TF214015 in the error finds only one unhelpful link.

Comment: Are you running with an account that has appropriate permissions? Also double check the version of the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client` as well to make sure that you are loading the right one.

Comment: I am using an admin account that should cover all permissions and I am running PowerShell as an Administrator.
Scanning the whole C:, I've got multiple copies of the DLL in various places but only two versions, 14.102.25423.0 and 14.0.23102.0. Loading in either version results in the same error stated above.

Answer (score 1):

When I experienced this (with TFS 2017 and assemblies even more up-to-date than freakydinde's out of date copies on GitHub) it was an error in the URI being passed in the construction of the `TfsTeamProjectCollection`.  The URI was `http://example.net/tfs/`, rather than `http://example.net/tfs/DefaultCollection/` which was of course the URI of the team project collection.

The same goes for calling `TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection()` in the API.

Erroneously accusing us of using TFS 2005 or TFS 2008 is, it seems, Microsoft's rather odd spelling of "That is not the URI of a 2013+ team project collection."  ☺

Answer (score 0):

i'm the writer of the mentionned article.

i think you are loading old TFS assemblies, you should take the kit from GITHUB and use the Modules-TFS.psm1 and\or Assemblies folder provided, dll are from TFS2015.

https://github.com/freakydinde/Powershell/tree/master/tfsKit